# How do I print a beta in TeX Gyre Termes text mode?

Tags: fonts, unicode

I have to write a document in Times. Therefore I started writing it in TeX Gyre Termes, based on the note on [Time's font page](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/times/). However, I use PDFLaTeX, so I can't directly type Greek characters. So if I want to write isopropyl-1-thio-β-D-galactopyranoside I need to type isopropyl-1-thio-$\beta$-D-galactopyranoside.

However, this puts the beta as italic (Which I need anyway, not bad) but lists it in a different font then the surrounding text. I noticed that [Times](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/times/) ( \usepackage{mathptmx} ) is listed as math-compatible, while TeX Gyre Termes is not, so I switched packages and lo and behold my beta now works.

However, I noticed that if you look through [Termes technical documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/fonts/tex-gyre/doc/fonts/tex-gyre/qtm-info.pdf) it lists it as having a beta, in normal, italic, bold and bold italic. (Character 03B2 on page 10, section 3. Standard other unicodes 0080 .. DFFF (actually in 00A0 .. uni2AB0))

Some examples with a MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
Hey, look, a $\beta$, that doesn't match the text. 
\end{document}
```

[image: tgtermes with a non-matching beta]

And a better looking example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
Hey, look, a $\beta$, that better matches the text. 
\end{document}
```

[image: A better looking beta from mathptmx]

I thought \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} would let me just type β and have it work, but no dice.

egreg also told me to try this:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{β}{\beta}


\begin{document}
Hey, look, a β that gives me gibberish
\end{document}
```

[image: newunicodechar gives me gibberish]

Which makes me wonder: 
1) In what way is Termes better then Times if it isn't math-mode usable? 
2) Can I use Times as my math-font and Termes as my body?
3) Can I get access to the 4 betas from Termes in PDFLaTeX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution that integrates cgnieder's and rdhs's:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{tgtermes,chemmacros}
\usepackage[artemisia]{textgreek}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \IfInIupac #1 #2
  { \bool_if:NTF \l_chemmacros_inside_iupac_bool {#1} {#2} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newunicodechar{β}{\IfInIupac{\Chembeta}{\ensuremath{\beta}}}
\newunicodechar{ᴅ}{\IfInIupac{\D}{\textsc{d}}}

\begin{document}

\iupac{isopropyl-1-thio-β-ᴅ-galactopyranoside}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Other equivalences can be defined similarly. If the upright beta is needed also in text, the best way is, in my opinion, not to use it in math at all and change the definition into

```
\newunicodechar{β}{\Chembeta}
```

Comment: In the standard setting of `chemmacros` `\D` is defined `\textsc{D}` in _and_ outside of `\iupac` so `\newunicodechar{ᴅ}{\D}` should suffice.

Comment: @cgnieder OK, but the same wouldn't be true for `\L`. A little overhead, but greater clarity. :-)

Comment: True. (Need some more text to get the 15 full :) )

Comment: Ok, I get the beta, but how on earth do I copy and paste a smallcaps D?

Comment: On another note: egreg, you finally pushed me over the edge and made me organize my \usepackage commands into sections.

Comment: Could I now add a \newcommand{\upbeta}{β}, so I don't have to find and copy a beta each time?

Comment: Can you explain why you did all that 'extra' coding instead of just using \b? Also if I wanted to override the defaults there is a mode for that.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can use `mathptmx` for math and `tgtermes` for text; just load both packages. The "gibberish" example doesn't work because you didn't set the input to UTF-8. Here's the fix:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{β}{\ensuremath{\beta}}
\newunicodechar{ᴅ}{\textsc{d}}

\begin{document}
isopropyl-1-thio-β-ᴅ-galactopyranoside
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also use [`mtpro2`](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html#MTPro2_Lite) instead of `mathptmx`, for a lighter `\beta` with an upright option:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mtpro2}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{β}{\ensuremath{\beta}}
%\newunicodechar{β}{\ensuremath{\upbeta}}
\newunicodechar{ᴅ}{\textsc{d}}

\begin{document}
isopropyl-1-thio-β-ᴅ-galactopyranoside
\end{document}
```

[image]

The Symbol font (`psy`) provides a text-mode beta for Times, but it's *only* available in upright:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mtpro2}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{β}{\Pisymbol{psy}{98}}
\newunicodechar{ᴅ}{\textsc{d}}

\begin{document}
isopropyl-1-thio-β-ᴅ-galactopyranoside
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How would I get access to the other betas in Terms? Is that possible?

Comment: @Canageek Not with (pdf)LaTeX, but only with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @Canageek The betas are in Termes's `otf` file, but not in the T1-encoded font available to `pdftex`. I'd think you could use the `otf` to make an LGR-encoded font which includes beta, and then switch to it using `babel` or such, as in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9226/9092) – but is it really worth that much effort?

Comment: If one loads `babel`, then
`\newunicodechar{β}{\textormath{{{\usefont{U}{psy}{m}{n}b}}}{\beta}}` would give an upright beta in text mode.

Comment: Probably not; I'll just leave it italic. I must say, the pain at using upright greek is really annoying, and probably the one place that TeX really gets its rear handed to it by Word.

Answer (score 7):

Since [IUPAC](http://www.iupac.org/) recommends an upright beta for such cases I'd probably just use the [`textgreek`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textgreek) package.

From the [IUPAC Green Book](http://old.iupac.org/publications/books/author/mills.html):

> Greek leers are used in systematic organic, inorganic, macromolecular
>   and biochemical nomenclature. These should be roman (upright), since
>   they are not symbols for physical quantities.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tgtermes,chemmacros}
\usepackage[artemisia]{textgreek}

% this will activate \b (= beta symbol) in normal text, too, instead of only
% inside \iupac:
% \chemsetup[option]{iupac=strict}
\begin{document}

\iupac{isopropyl-1-thio-\b-\D-galactopyranoside}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To have `textgreek` use Symbol's beta: `\def\textgreekfontmap{{qtm/*/*}{U/psy/*/*}}`

Comment: @rdhs can you elaborate on this? What is the purpose/the benefit?

Comment: Symbol's upright beta matches *exactly* the slanted beta from `mathptmx`, since Symbol was designed to match Times.

Comment: @rdhs But why should I want to use `textgreek` then in the first place? Seems like a detour to me.