# Upright Lowercase $\pi$

Tags: math-mode, isomath

On pg. 144 of Kopka and Daily's *A Guide to LaTeX*, they mention that the symbols `$e$`, `$i$`, `$d$`, and `$\pi$` should be displayed upright in math mode (for their usual uses).  This is easy to do for `$e$`, `$i$`, and `$d$`:  just use `\mathrm`.  However, this does nothing to `\pi`.  How exactly do you generate an upright `\pi` in math mode?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Is there a well-known math book that actually does this?

Comment: Is MathJax not activated on this website?  The inline LaTeX wasn't typetset.  I would have thought that inline LaTeX would be functional on, you know, a QA site for TeX . . . (I know it t works on Mathematics StackExchange and Physics StackExchange.  Why not here?)

Comment: @JonathanGleason: See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/why-doesnt-maths-render-as-maths

Comment: Related - https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145926/128462

Comment: @DylanMoreland, I don't know how I would quantify well-known-ness, but The Princeton Companion to Mathematics ([JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt7sd01), [zbMATH](https://zbmath.org/?format=complete&q=an:1242.00016)) sets Euler's number ‘e’, the imaginary ‘i’, and the differential ‘d’ in upright type, although it doesn't seem to do this with ‘π’.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

One option could be to use `\uppi` from the `upgreek` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\begin{document}

$\uppi$

$\pi$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the upright symbol using the `Symbol` package option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[Symbol]{upgreek}

\begin{document}

$\uppi$

$\pi$

\end{document}
```

[image]

and now using the `Symbolsmallscale` package option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[Symbolsmallscale]{upgreek}

\begin{document}

$\uppi$

$\pi$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The two options for upright π that `upgreek.sty` provides don't match Computer Modern too well in my opinion. For example the π above looks far too wide in comparison to the italic greek one.

Answer (score 18):

Without [`upgreek`](http://ctan.org/pkg/upgreek), [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel) supports upright Greek characters:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\gpi}{\textrm{\greektext p}}
$\gpi \theta$
\end{document}
```

(Taken from [Upright Greek letters in text mode (not `upgreek`)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9219/5764).)

Comment: Using the `textgreek` package is easier.

Answer (score 13):

With Xe/LuaLaTeX, `unicode-math` and a proper OpenType Math font, upright πs (and many other symbols) are built in:

```
% compile with xelatex or lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{lmmath-regular.otf}

\begin{document}
$π\ \mathrm{π}$
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: And of course for old pi-syntax: `$\pi \mathup{\pi}$`. Just in case you don't want to copy the uni-code symbol somewhere.

Answer (score 11):

While `upgreek` works well for some fonts, it doesn't match perfectly with Computer Modern. Here are some alternatives:

- Use a different typeface for the document. For example BT Charter from `mathdesign`<sup>(1)</sup>:

  ```
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[charter,cal=cmcal]{mathdesign}
  ```
- Use the text pi that you get when typing Greek text with e.g. babel:

  ```
  \usepackage[greek,english]{babel} % english = default
  \usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{lmodern,amsmath,xspace}
  \def\PI{\ensuremath{\text{\foreignlanguage{greek}{p}}}\xspace}
  % Similar definitions can be made for the rest of the greek alphabet. 
  % Here's a conversion table:
  % Latin: a b g d e z h j i k l m n x o p r s t u f q y w 
  % Greek: α β γ δ ε ζ η θ ι κ λ μ ν ξ ο π ρ σ τ υ φ χ ψ ω
  ```

  While this *works* it's really ugly and should obviously be done with `\DeclareSymbolFont` and `\DeclareMathSymbol`.
- Same as the above, but using the font `bodoni` instead. It's a Didone typeface, so it should match pretty well with Computer Modern.

(1): Note that mathdesign has some other design issues such as imperfect kerning, poorly drawn glyphs for blackboard bold letters and `\middle\vert` usually ends up being too high.

Answer (score 10):

From [Will Robertson's blog](http://latex-alive.tumblr.com/post/698006466) one way is to use the `mathpazo`.  Here is a comparison of the two:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\DeclareSymbolFont{euler}{U}{eur}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol \uppi \mathalpha {euler} {"19}

\begin{document}
    $\pi \quad \uppi$
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's also possible to use π from the default Greek text font, but I'm not sure which font the symbol is from nor what its number in it is. π from `bodoni` should also match pretty well with Computer Modern since they are both Didone typefaces.

Comment: Expanding on my previous comment on using the Greek text font, one can achieve that like this, but it's a *really* roundabout (and brittle) way of doing it: `\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{lmodern,amsmath,xspace} \def\PI{\ensuremath{\text{\foreignlanguage{greek}{p}}}\xspace}`

Comment: @kahen: You should post an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Besides the solutions above, I have recently come across the isomath package and found that page 6 of its manual provides a fairly good summary for available ways to get upright small greek letters.

(One of) the link to the manual itself is:
http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/isomath/isomath.pdf

And I take the liberty of taking a screenshot of the relevant page for your convenience:

[image: Extracted from latex package isomath manual v.2012.9.4 page 6]

Comment: even more options: look at the `chemgreek` package (another use case but it lists quite a few packages…)