Unicode-math not working
I am typing article on overleaf, I want to have access to \symrm (for example to write \symrm{\pi}}.
Everytime I write usepackage{unicode-math} error appears indicating to use lualatex or xetex instead.
Can you provide your input on this problem? For example how to obtain \symrm{\pi} ?

(We are following the not so short introduction to latex, \symrm was used over there).

you are using the wrong engine. Switch to lualatex in the menu.

can you elaborate? You mean usepackage lualatex?

go to menu (left top in overleaf), click on it, then go to compiler and switch there to lualatex.

I see, are there other ways to obtain the same form as \symrm{\pi} as in the not so short introduction to latex?

there are a number of upright pi with pdflatex here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54166/upright-lowercase-pi, but why don't you want to use lualatex?

By the way, \symrm is slightly obsolete -- and maybe even deprecated, as it's no longer mentioned in the user guide of the unicode-math package. I suggest you use \symup instead.

@UlrikeFischer Noticed that Lualatex changes the style, for example \symbb is not similar to \mathbb that we usually obtain in pdflatex. is there a way to prevent that?

you can change a lot of things in unicode-math, but imho it would be better not to fight against it. lualatex + unicode is not the same as pdflatex and 8-bit fonts, so do not try to imitate pdflatex output.
