# How to typeset this complex-ish symbol?

Tags: symbols

I'm looking for some ideas on how to typeset this image in LaTeX. I tried using the math mode, but I couldn't make the lambda greater than the text sub- and superscripted. I also tried `{\huge \textlambda}`, using the `textgreek` package, but that didn't work either.

[image: lambda^{MeOH}_{200--600}]

Comment: Are you _sure_ you need an upright lambda? Just wondering since this looks like a physical quantity and it's rather unusual to typeset those upright...

Comment: @cgnieder you're right; I came to the same conclusion after I saw @Werner's answer, so I just used `\lambda` in math mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not entirely sure where you're interested in using the symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}% http://ctan.org/pkg/greek
\newcommand{\upgreek}[1]{\text{\greektext #1\latintext}}
\begin{document}
$\upgreek{\Huge l}^{\text{MeOH}}_{\text{200-600}}$
\end{document}
```

You can also use `\lambda`, or any of the options in [Upright Greek letters in text mode (not upgreek)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9219/5764).