# greek in latex-template thesis

Tags: templates, greek

I am using TexMaker and I have just found a beautiful template for my thesis http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis

I have the problem that i can't write greeks.

I have tried to add the following commands

`\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}` and
`\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}`

but it returns errors.

any advice?

Comment: Is your thesis in Greek, or do you have only some parts in Greek and the main language is English?

Comment: Have you seen and tried all the ways described in [How to typeset greek letters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69901) and [Upright Greek letters in text mode (not upgreek)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9219)?

Answer (score 1):

The following

```
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
```

should work.

Comment: nice,thanks!. i have added these lines in main.tex and it works. But if i add them in Thesis.cls, it doesn't work. For example i changed the line \authors{John \textsc{Smith}} to \authors{\selectlanguage{greek} Νίκος} and it returns errors. How could i write greeks in Thesis.cls file?

Comment: @DimitrisKlinos Author inside *.cls? What a horrible solution! But you can freely change the appearance of a title page in your thesis. This seems to be the only place where the author is needed.